# Horizontal website with two content areas

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, scrolltop

I'm creating a site where there are two distinct areas. The idea is that I click a button and the second content area slides in on top of the first.

Both areas are set to 100% width and are positioned absolutely so as to take up the whole window width.

For the second area (hidden on page load) I'm using a higher z-index and margin-left of 98% so as to just show the button to click.

In jQuery upon click of that button a class is toggled whereby the margin-left moves from 98% to 0 and so now the hidden area is displayed instead.

All that works fine except that the hidden area has a much higher height than the first. I have set it up so that when the first content area is visible, the body has overflow:hidden and when the second, overflow:visible.

The problem is that if I scroll down on the second area and then click to slide back to the first, the first area will have overflow:hidden but not display from the top.

I have tried without success to scrollTop before and after the class is toggled.

I did try replicating this in jsfiddle but as it's 100% of viewport it's very hard to show, I'm sorry for being overly verbose! Attached is a simple screenshot.

Would be great if anyone had any ideas, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page here: [cargocollective.com/nonfeed](http://cargocollective.com/nonfeed)

It seems like what you need is to scroll the right div without actually scrolling the entire page. In this design example, there are three divs for each vertical scroll section that look like the following:

```
div.entry {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.entry div.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
div.entry div.wrapper div.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

For your situation, you probably want to just wrap the right div in another div with `overflow: hidden`, and then have a jQuery function to set the height of the div to the height of your page.

Here's some jQuery code that sets the window height:

```
var height_change_callback = function() {
var bodyheight = jQuery(window).height();
jQuery(".wrapper").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).css("height", bodyheight-80);
    });
}
jQuery(document).ready(height_change_callback);
// for the window resize
jQuery(window).resize(height_change_callback);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: upon looking for another few seconds, you may just be able to get away with only having the height change callback on your right div, and not adding any extra wrapper divs at all. The cargocollective example is also set up to hide all scroll bars, so I think that's the purpose of the div.entry.

Comment: Thanks so much @acsmith, I think you are right, I have it working by just having my second page content (which is a grid-block gallery) set up to scroll and not change the height at all (I think in hindsight it's a more graceful solution). Great link, that's really interesting what they've done.